# "Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have..." - solution this warning

Tags: ios, objective-c

The full warning is

> Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an
>   identifier for runtime access via-
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.

I have used Xcode-7.01, why this warning is coming and what is the solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix that issue in two ways.

1. Specify a segue to that view controller
2. Specify a storyboard identifier for that particular scene

[image: Storyboard ID]

Comment: The warnings stay even after adding storyboard id. One of my view controller even got two warnings with repeated message. (I'm using XCode 8)

Answer (score 2):

When the scene is the only scene in the storyboard, you might need to specify that your viewController is the initial view controller, like this:

[image: set initial ViewController]

This creates an entry point for the storyboard. If the entry point is another viewController, create a segue to or provide a storyboard ID for the problematic scene, like Midhun MP suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario but i dont even have an application scene.

Comment: @Midhun MP give the solution solution ans. for my ques.